# MLMultiArray use of undeclared type error

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, undeclared-identifier, coremltools

I am attempting to set up the input for a coreML model, which takes as input an MLMultiArray. I have referenced solutions on this site for how to convert a Double array to a MLMultiArray. However, I am getting the "use of undeclared type" error for MLMultiArray.

[screenshot of the error and "my" code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgaHh.png)

Alternatively, do you have any suggestions for how to instead set up a model to take a 1D Double array instead? My model is a SVR converted from sklearn.

I am using Xcode 9.2, but as soon as I post this I will update to 9.3 to see if that helps.

Thank you very much.

(also, don't worry--I have cited the relevant stack overflow sources in my header!)

Comment: Did you `import CoreML`?

Comment: No I didn't vadian. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

@import CoreML

You need to import the framework in your class.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer such a basic question.